# How to validate password length and regex same time

Tags: reactjs, react-native, yup

I'm using `yup` for validation, it look like this

```
export const signinSchema = yupResolver(
  yup.object().shape({
    username: yup.string().required("Email is a required field."),
    password: yup
      .string()
      .required("Password is a required field.")
      .matches(/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@#$%^&+=])/, {
        message:
          "Password must be at least one uppercase, one lowercase, one special character and one number.",
      })
      .min(8, "Password must be at least 8 charaters."),
  }),
)
```

But i wonder can we validate password length ( `.min(8, "Password must be at least 8 charaters."` ) and regex (

```
.matches(/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@#$%^&+=])/, {
        message:
          "Password must be at least one uppercase, one lowercase, one special character and one number.",
      })
```

**At the same time?? like combine two condition into one**

Thank you guy a lot

Comment: Your password validation is bad for UX. You should separate your validation rules. 
 Each rule should only do one thing.   One rule for uppercase, one for lowercase, one for required, etc.  Without separating them you can only return generic messages which don't tell users what exactly is wrong with their input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following regex pattern:

```regex
/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@#$%^&+=]).{8,}$/
                                                ^^^ change is here
```

This would require a lowercase and uppercase letter, digit, special character, and 8 or more total characters.  As the comment above suggests, you might want to separate out the pattern for each condition, if you intend to provide feedback for each rule one at a time.